# Java gui not working properly

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have the following code to set up a gui to input source and target language from user using a JComboBox but on running it nothing except the button is displayed please suggest something.I have done initialization and all other stuff in the constructor.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class SrcAndTargLangInput implements ActionListener {
    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JComboBox sourcLang;
    public static JComboBox targLang;
    public static JLabel setSrcLang;
    public static JLabel setTargLang;
    public static JButton ok;
    String[] lang = new String[2];

    public SrcAndTargLangInput() {
        ok = new JButton("Ok");
        ok.setBounds(150, 400, 100, 50);
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(ok);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Insets ins = frame.getInsets();
        frame.setSize(400 + ins.left + ins.right, 500 + ins.bottom + ins.top);
        setSrcLang = new JLabel("Source Language");
        setSrcLang.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 40);
        setTargLang = new JLabel("Target Language");
        setTargLang.setBounds(50, 200, 100, 40);
        String[] srcLangList = { "English", "Spanish", "French" };
        sourcLang = new JComboBox(srcLangList);
        sourcLang.setBounds(250, 100, 100, 40);
        String[] targLangList = { "English", "Spanish", "French" };
        targLang = new JComboBox(targLangList);
        targLang.setBounds(250, 200, 100, 40);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        ok.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new SrcAndTargLangInput();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        lang[0] = (sourcLang.getSelectedItem().toString());
        lang[1] = (targLang.getSelectedItem().toString());
        frame.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you double check your code first? You've added your `JButton` to your frame's content pane but you have not added your `JComboBox`. There is also no need to call  `frame.setVisible(true);` twice; simply call it once you are done adding elements to the frame.

Finally, you should not be running your Swing GUI code outside of the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) or you may run into problems later with threading. Change your main method to:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new SrcAndTargLangInput();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not to mention public and static modifier over-use syndrome! 1+